# Jquery: add .attr() from different parent

Tags: jquery

I had a Accept button on my modal, what I want is when I press Accept automatically it will give 'checked' attribute to the `#check-agree` id, but the problem here is I don't know how to reach `#check-agree` from `.modal-accept` here is my code :

```
<div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check-agree">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="check-agree">Agree our <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" href="">terms and conditions</a></label>
            </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-accept" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<script>
$(".modal-accept").click(function(){
  $('#check-agree').attr("checked")
});
</script>
```

Comment: dont matter how far #check-agree from .modal-accept. Your example is correct, just try $('#check-agree').attr("checked", true) but make sure about #check-agree exists!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the checkbox, use

```
$('#check-agree').attr("checked", true)
```